# HOW to change property of custom cell from IBAction method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**i have table view which has custom cell.**

***the custom cell class has this property:***

```
@property (nonatomic,retain ) IBOutlet ASStarRatingView *editableStarRatingView;
```

***the method cellforRowAtindexPath has :***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        cell.editableStarRatingView.canEdit = YES;
        cell.editableStarRatingView.maxRating = 5;
        cell.editableStarRatingView.rating=0;
        cell.editableStarRatingView.hidden = YES;
}
```

***then the IBAction method :***

```
- (IBAction)AddRate:(id)sender {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";

    PlacesDetailsCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.editableStarRatingView.hidden=YES;

}
```

**But the editableStarRatingView still there and doesn't hide !.**

Comment: Can you explain what do you want ? Do you want `editableStarRatingView` in all your cells to be hidden or just certain one.

Comment: @kudocc yes i want editableStarRatingView to be hidden in all cells after you click on certain button !.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all `editableStarRatingView` in cells, try this.

Declare a BOOL value, let's say it `BOOL hide;` with `NO` as default value.

In `- (IBAction)AddRate:(id)sender` method, set `hide` to `YES`, then reload the tableview.

```
- (IBAction)AddRate:(id)sender
{
    hide = !hide ;
    [myTable reloadData] ;
}
```

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, hide `editableStarRatingView` when hide is YES.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.editableStarRatingView.canEdit = YES;
    cell.editableStarRatingView.maxRating = 5;
    cell.editableStarRatingView.rating=0;
    cell.editableStarRatingView.hidden = hide ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PlacesDetailsCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
This is used to get a reuse cell from the pool instead of getting a specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

Now I get you were looking for. Although you have already accepted the answer, I wanted to post this answer because there is a better way of doing this. Instead of reloading the entire table which will call cellForRowAtIndexPath multiple times (based on number of visible cells), you can simply load the tapped cell after hiding the view in it. Please try with below code:

```
- (IBAction)AddRate:(id)sender {
    CGPoint center = ((ASStarRatingView *)sender).center;
    CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];

    UITableViewCell *tapppedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tapppedCell.editableStarRatingView.hidden = YES;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```